# Remover App da Apple Store

Tags: ios, xamarin-forms, apple

Existe um App publicado na Apple Store. Recebi uma ordem para remover esse App, pois o mesmo vai subir com outro nome. Como eu faço para remover o App?

OBS Remover da Apple Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Você pode subir uma nova versão e atualiar o nome se quiser.
>   1- Para remover acesse https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ faça login com uma conta que tenha o app de deseja remover.
>   2 - Clique em "My apps" -> em "App Information" -> role a tela ate o fim e clique em "Remove app"